# Granting SAMBA rights and privileges requires root password

Tags: ubuntu, root, samba

Given a default Ubuntu installation, I get the following

```
myusername@EARTH:~$ sudo bash
root@EARTH:~# net rpc rights grant myusername SePrintOperatorPrivilege
Enter root's password:
Failed to grant privileges for myusername (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
```

Is there any workaround or do I really have to resort to unlocking the root account and setting its password?

Answer (score 1):

I think the command you typed is using the old syntax. This is working for me on a 4.3.9:

```
$ sudo net sam rights grant 'COMPUTER_NAME\myusername' SeDiskOperatorPrivilege
```

If Linux computer host name is "SERVER" & username is "testuser", then:

```
$ sudo net sam rights grant 'SERVER\testuser' SeDiskOperatorPrivilege
```

cf, [this mail thread](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2014-April/180369.html).

Answer (score -1):

Most probably this happens when using deprecated `security = share`.

```
security = user
map to guest = bad user
```

should fix the problem